# why need to deal with the fragmentation of messages

Tags: java, c++, networking, tcp, netty

the fragmentation of messages is done at IP , why i have to deal with that in application layer. such as mina or netty?

the fragmentation of messages will be right order, is right?

so any decoder need not to deal with any order question, is right?

Comment: I don't understand your question, can you be more explicit?

Answer (score 2):

Reassembly of IP packets is done completely at the IP layer (before UDP or TCP ever sees the packet) so you don't have to deal with "defragmentation" at the application layer.

Of course, this only applies to UDP since it is *packet* based while TCP is a *stream* and thus has no strict concept of packets from the point of view of the user.

TCP is free to transmit the outgoing bytes in any grouping it sees fit and the receiving side is free to pass the received bytes up to the application in any grouping it sees fit.  This allows a lot of flexibility to the TCP implementation in that it can group outgoing `send()` calls for more efficient transmission or break them up if they're too big for some point along the path.

You *must* think of TCP as just a stream of bytes (like coming from a serial port) when receiving the data; you could get any number of bytes at any time.  The order is guaranteed but not the grouping.

In practice, the grouping often *does* match how the data was sent which leaves applications that work much of the time but not all the time.

Answer (score 0):

You're right about the order part. Part 2 of a message will be visible no earlier than part 1, even if it physically did arrive earlier. But it's quite possible that part 2 of a message is visible *later* than part 1 of a message. And since TCP has no idea about message boundaries (it works on bytes), you just get half a message.

Comment: All true but not related.  Reassembly of the IP packet is done before it is passed up to TCP so TCP will have no idea whether the packet was fragmented or not and thus will behave the same regardless.

Comment: Not related? I'm just describing the guarantees (and lack thereof) of TCP without worrying about the underlying causes.